# How to make carousel image slide in php laravel from public folder

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, carousel

[image]I'm trying to slide images using carousel from public folder of php laravel. The files are loading as the images that i have posted. But i wanted to slide one after the other. None of the methods are working. It's only showing images one by one all at once. Kindly please look into it and help me.

The codes for view page is.

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

         <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    @foreach($images as $key => $image)
                       <li data-target="#home_main-slider" data-slide-to="{{$key}}" class="carousel-1">
                       </li>
                      @endforeach
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    @foreach( $images as $image )

                     @if ($loop->first)
                      <div class="item image active">
                      @else
                      <div class="item image">
                      @endif

                            <img src="{{ asset('img/' . $image->getFilename()) }}">
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
    </div>


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>

    </a>
```

the controller page code is..

```
 public function testimonials() {
        $titleName = "Testimonials";
        $images = \File::allFiles(public_path('img'));

        return view('testimonials', compact('titleName'))->with('images', $images);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

You'll need to import BS3 JS and jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Codepen Link**

Here is a BS3 Carousel example that might help - includes all the necessary JS and CSS. [codepen.io/darrenkhouston/pen/vYOKjzP](https://codepen.io/darrenkhouston/pen/vYOKjzP)

Comment: This looks like a Bootstrap 3 Carousel? Do you have your JavaScript for Bootstrap imported into the page somewhere? That is required for this carousel to work properly.

Comment: `
<script>
        (function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.carousel').jcarousel({
            wrap: 'circular'
        });
    });
})
    </script>`

Comment: That's to start the carousel. Do you have the Bootstrap JS imported as well?

`<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: You will also need jQuery imported before your Bootstrap JS. 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: If you have all of that taken care of and it still doesn't work, there may be discrepancies with how your code is configured. If you have a repo or something you can link to, I can attempt to pull it and help you out.

Comment: Gonna need some more clarity to get it working exactly how you want. Here is a BS3 Carousel example that might help - includes all the necessary JS and CSS. https://codepen.io/darrenkhouston/pen/vYOKjzP

Comment: Please mark updated answer as resolved, that would help out a lot. Thanks.